# Are badges with a negative connotation useful?

Tags: discussion

This is a very minor point.  I'm just curious to see what the thoughts might be on this.  I just "earned" a tumbleweed badge.  In the past I associated badges with good things but it seems this is not always the case.

If the purpose of a badge is to inform the user about his questions then I could see the utility.

If the purpose of a badge is to contribute to the overall stickiness of stack exchange sites through a merit based reward system, I think it's less useful.

Comment: For some more discussion, see [this meta.SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1576/130186), specifically about the Tumbleweed badge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not bad to ask a question without any attention or at least it's not the questioner's fault. (If a question is bad it usually get downvotes and maybe it will be closed.)

I think the tumbleweed badge encourages people to not leave the site and ask other questions in the future although they don't get answer for all of their questions. I think it's a good thing.

Comment: Good point.  How about a badge that looks at all the questions on the site that you *haven't* answered and uses AI to determine that you could have... the SLACKER badge :)